# MT4 expert trade panel - "OBJ_RECTANGLE_LABEL"

Tags: algorithmic-trading, mql4, metatrader4

MetaTrader4 Expert Advisor for Trade Panel.
How can I link some **`OBJ_RECTANGLE_LABEL`** for moving with another single object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Link 'em indirectly

There is no direct support for linking a few GUI-objects to move with another one.

This does not mean, it is not possible to have it working like this.

In one Augmented Trader UI-tool, I needed to have both all the GUI-components and some computed values behaving under some similar logic ( keeping all the lines, rectangles, text labels and heat-map colors, under some common UI-control-logic ). All the live-interactive-GUI orchestration was locked onto a few permited user-machine interactions, where the user was able to move with a set of UI-control-objects, some of which were freely modify-able, whereas some were restricted ( with the use of the augmented reality controllers ) to move just vertically or just horizontally or were just locked to start as tangents from the edges of Bollinger Bands in such a place, where the vertical line of the UI-control-object was moved by the user, etc.

### The Live-interactive-GUI solution is simple:

Besides the **[** Expert Advisor **]** create and run another process, the **[** Script **]** that would be responsible for the GUI-object automation. Within this script, use some read-only values from objects, let's say a blue vertical line, as a **`SENSOR_x1`**, an input to the GUI-composition.

If someone or something moves this blue vertical line, your event-watching loop inside the script will detect a new value for the **`SENSOR_x1`**
and
re-process all the UI-layout scheme by adding the just observed / detected motion of a **`SENSOR_x1_delta = SENSOR_x1 - SENSOR_x1_previous;`**
This way, one can update the motion detector-loop in the **[** Script **]**, chasing all the **`SENSOR_*`** actual values and promoting the detected **`SENSOR_*_delta`**-s onto all objects, that are being used in the  GUI-layout composition.

Finally it is worth to stage the updates of the screen with a few enforced **`WindowRedraw();`** instructions, throughout the re-processing of the augmented reality in the Live-interactive-GUI.

### Code from a PoC-demonstrator

[image]

One may notice, the code is in a pre-*New*-`MQL4.56789` syntax, using some there permitted variable naming conventions, that ceased to be permitted now. The scope of the Event-Monitor function ( a self-contained function, optimised for max speed / min latency in handling all the three corners of the MVC-framework ( **Model**-is Live-GUI project-specific, **Visual**-is the Live-GUI augmentation-specific, **Controller**-is flexible and composed as a sort of Finite-State-Machine, from principal building blocks and implemented via **`"object.method"`** calls in the `switch(){}`. Loop sampling rate works great down to few tens of milliseconds, so the Live-GUI is robust and smoothly floating on the Trader's Desk.

Comment: Updated with an example from a Live-GUI PoC above.

Comment: Until now you helped me a lot, big thanks for that, I highly appreciate that. So I am hard working for it.

Comment: Specially ("Wild Worlds of MQL4" & happy and successfull trading) you too - Really I liked your comment. I already clicked for vote up. :) - of course I will do it continuously.

Answer (score 1):

This is not best way but schematically shows what to do.

```
string      mainObjectNAME,
       dependantObjectNAME;                     // dependant - your obj label

void OnChartEvent( const int     id,
                   const long   &lparam,
                   const double &dparam,
                   const string &sparam
                   ){
   if (  id == CHARTEVENT_OBJECT_DRAG
      || id == CHARTEVENT_OBJECT_ENDEDIT
         ){
      if (  StringCompare( sparam, mainObjectNAME ) == 0 ){
            datetime time1  = (datetime) ObjectGetInteger( 0,      mainObjectNAME, OBJPROP_TIME1 );
            double   price1 =            ObjectGetDouble(  0, dependantObjectNAME, OBJPROP_PRICE1 );
            if ( !ObjectMove( 0, dependantObjectNAME, 0, time1, price1 ) )
                  Print( __LINE__,
                         "failed to move object ",
                         dependantObjectNAME
                         );
      }
      ChartRedraw();
   }
}
```

if you modify the `mainObject` by any of the recognised means ( by dragging or passing other parameters ) - then dependant object ( **`OBJ_RECT_LABEL`** in your case ) is moved with `ObjectMove()` or `ObjectSet()` functions.

Comment: The adverse side of this proposal is, that it unconditionally repaints the whole GUI-composition. If the augmented trading GUI consists of many dependant objects, some possibly being re-calculated based upon an event of change, the whole circus will run even for objects, that do not move/change thus lossing efficiency, which in terms of the Live-interactive-GUI means, the main event-loop looses it's responsiveness and the GUI starts to become slow and delayed in ( completely ) refreshing itself. Plus, **this wil never work in [ Script ],** so the most time-critical code will have to wait in EA

Comment: Thanks man. I will try it as soon as possible. I highly appreciate that.

Comment: yes i agree. If you have many objects on chart - it may lose efficiency.